# php variable in javascript variable jqgrid integration

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I've a php function to get some data from mysql database:

```
function get_persons() {
    $result=dbquery("SELECT id,name,surname FROM ".DB_PERSONS." ORDER BY id ASC");
    while ($person = dbarray($result)){
        $id=$person['id'];
        echo "<option value='$id'>$person['name'] - $person['surname']</option>";
    }
}
```

And i've a javascript code:

```
$edit_buttonoptions = array("#pager", 
    array("title"=>"Takım Seç","buttonicon"=>"ui-icon-mail-open","caption"=>"Takım Seç", "onClickButton"=>"js: 
 var jspersonvar;
 jspersonvar = "<?php get_persons();?>"
function(){
    var selr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    var rowData = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getRowData', selr);
    var kelr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', selr, 'bilinen_adi');
    var fotograf = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', selr, 'logo');
    if(selr)
        miktar=miktar+1,
        pp='takimlar',
        nm=pp + miktar,
        jQuery('#takimlar').append('<div id=' + nm + '>'),
        jQuery('#'+ nm +'').append('<div style=text-align:center;>'+fotograf+'<input type=hidden name=takim'+ miktar +' value=' + selr + ' />'),
        jQuery('#'+ nm +'').append('<select name=sezon'+ miktar +' id=sezon'+ miktar +'>'+jspersonvar+'</select>'),
        jQuery('#'+ nm +'').append('' + kelr + ''),
        jQuery('#'+ nm +'').append('</div>'),
        jQuery('#'+ nm +'').append('</div><br />'),

      alert('' + kelr + ' Takımı Seçildi')
    else
    alert('Lütfen Bir Takım Seçiniz!')
    return false;
    }"),
); 
$grid->callGridMethod("#grid", "navButtonAdd", $edit_buttonoptions);
```

It doesn't work, I've tried several things but no luck...

Comment: What is expected? And what dosen't work?

Comment: put `"` around `<?php get_persons(); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the variable in quotes as it will look like this when the server renders the page:

```
jspersonvar = <option value='$id'>......
```

When you have quotes around it, `jspersonvar` will be treated as a string and you can do what you will with it.

```
jspersonvar = "<?php get_persons();?>"
```

Just be warned, any `"` in your database that get displayed will screw up your javascript.